# I can't install the ADT plugin for eclipse 3.5.2 on windows XP(32bit)

Tags: android, plugins, adt

I had installed jdk,sdk,eclipse,and set the path.i will show the jdk-version,sdk.

jdk version test:

C:>java -version
java version "1.6.0_10"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_10-b33)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.0-b15, mixed mode, sharing)

sdk test:

C:>android -help
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client       to select the "client" VM    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

```
-cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
-classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
```

the eclipse version:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers---Eclipse Galileo SR2 Packages (v 3.5.2)

but have a question when i install the ADT: i install it online,the url
the question is :

you are installing software that contains unsigned content.The authenticity or validity of this software cannot be established.

Answer (score 0):

Just accept it and allow it to install.